# How is the search on Library of Babel SO fast?

Tags: string, search, random, search-engine

Here's a description of the Library of Babel from user @David

> The Library of Babel website ([libraryofbabel.info](http://libraryofbabel.info)) contains books
>   with pseudorandomly generated text, each with 410 pages and located on
>   a "floor," "wall," and "shelf" of the library. Any sequence of less
>   than 3200 characters (including all 26 letters and the period, space,
>   and comma) can be found inside at least one of the books.

On the site, you can search for a string (upto 3200 characters), and the site will return 3 results:
1) Just that string of text by itself, which is a unique page
2) Wherever that string occurs amidst random characters
3) Wherever that string occurs amidst random combinations of actual english words

It boggles me how *fast* that search is. Presumably, the site doesn't actually store any pages, it's all algorithmically generated (correct me if I'm wrong). If that's the case, how can it, almost instantaneously, generate all possible combinations, divide them up into random characters, vs english words, and tell me how many pages the string shows up in? Even if there is some statistical handwaviness going on, where if it tells me there are 78482018 pages that match my query, it's more of an estimate, it still returns me 20 pages right away. No seriously. *Right. Away.*

**How can it be so fast?**

Comment: Most likely, they're using a weak RNG where you can mathematically determine what seed will produce a given output sequence. We can't tell without seeing the source, though.

Comment: Thanks; What's a weak RNG?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=rng

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I should have said what's a "weak RNG". I searched google, and the best I could come up with is that it has something to do with encryption and being easily deciphered?

Comment: Weak as in predictable. Given a certain amount of output, you can tell what the seed is and what future output will be.

Comment: So does that mean that given a string, the algorithm can likely guess the seed? So if I search for "stackoverflow" in the library of babel, there's an algorithm which can determine which sets of 3200 characters will contain the string and return them instantaneously?

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: This is sort of a math answer

The library of babel does not actually store anything, that would mean storing 29^3200 books.

First, I'll start off by explaining a what a pseudorandom function is. A good pseudorandom function will generate a sequence of numbers that seems random, but can be predicted given enough information.

Take for example, the function

f(x) = x^2 + c mod n, where c and n are constant

If we start with x=2, c=1, and n=20, by repeatedly applying f(x) to the previous result (iterating f(x)), we will get the sequence

2, 5, 6, 17, 10, 1, 2 ... and the cycle restarts...

So if we know c, n, and the starting value of x (called the seed), the following numbers can be predicted with ease. For example, with a seed of 6, you can predict that the numbers following will be 17, 10, and 1. If you wanted to remember the sequence 17, 10, 1, you would only need to remember the seed (17), and the length of the sequence (3).

If you were to enumerate the complete sequence generated by the function that the Library of Babel uses, until it looped back to the first number, you would end up with a string that contains all* possible 3200 character substrings. To find a substring, you only need the seed.

The final trick is to find a function that is *invertible*, which means that given a [sub]sequence, the seed can be found. Many pseudorandom functions can be reverse engineered without much effort, but in the case of the Library of Babel, it took some effort.

*almost all